# Hitting API Gateway resource limit

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

We're migrating an existing API away from a custom gateway solution and to AWS API Gateway. Our API has around 600 endpoints and, to migrate it to API Gateway, we would need around 650 resources. Now, the standard limit is 300, and I am aware I can ask for an increase on that - I just did, and hopefully it will get approved.

However, since I'm more than doubling the default cap, I can't help but wonder if I'm taking the wrong approach here, so I wanted to learn how other people tackled similar challenges. Our current plan was to have a single API Gateway instance account for all endpoints, which would then point to different TCP ports on a AWS NLB, with each port being forwarded to a Kubernetes NodePort Service.

Has anyone had to migrate a similarly sized API to AWS API Gateway, and faced similar challenges? If so, what was your approach to this?

Comment: Facebook solved this problem by inventing GraphQL, which requires *one* endpoint.